# How to keep unique rows in a data frame using `dplyr::distinct()` while specifying precision on numerical variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's an example of keeping unique rows based on the `Sepal.Length` column only using `dplyr::distinct()`. This removes already many rows, from 150 rows in the original `iris` data set to 35 rows after the application of `dplyr::distinct()`.

Instead of having `dplyr::distinct()` making an exact comparison, I would like to provide a level of numerical precision on the deviations, let us say 10%.

For example, the first two observations shown below for the `Sepal.Length` variable, show `5.1` and `4.9`, respectively. That means a difference of `0.2`. If we make that relative to the highest value, i.e. `5.1`, then we have a relative difference of 0.2 / 5.1 = 0.03921569 (3.9%).

Hence, according to the criterion of 10%, these two observations should be considered equal, as 3.9% < 10 %.

So, is there a simple and idiomatic way of doing this? I mean without resorting to explicitly having me calculating distances between all observations for each variable of interest and then applying filters...?

Am I underestimating the problem, and this really requires, perhaps, clustering of the values to define "equal" groups, and is therefore a difficult problem that goes beyond the scope of `dplyr`, and `distinct()` particularly?

If I am answering my own question with these suppositions, I think it might still be useful to leave it here posted for others that might be approaching this question as naively as me.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
distinct(iris, Sepal.Length, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#> 7           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 8           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 9           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> 10          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 11          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 12          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 13          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 14          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 15          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 16          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 17          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 18          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 19          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#> 20          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
#> 21          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 22          5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor
#> 23          6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
#> 24          6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 25          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 26          6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#> 27          6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 28          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#> 29          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
#> 30          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
#> 31          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
#> 32          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica
#> 33          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#> 34          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
#> 35          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of identifying relative distance from column max and using this as some sort of grouping you could use the following approach for one column. The important part is to round the calculation result to i.e. 10% steps mean one digit after the decimal separator:

```
iris %>%
    dplyr::transmute(Sepal.Length = round((max(Sepal.Length) - Sepal.Length) / max(Sepal.Length), 1)) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()
```

and if you like to use it for all numerical columns a generalization of the above solution looks like this

```
iris %>%
    dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round((max(.x) - .x) / max(.x), 1))) %>%
    dplyr::distinct()
```

if you want to add new columns with the max distance of eacht column, this can be an option:

```
iris  %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
                       .fns = list(dist_max = ~round((max(.x) - .x) / max(.x), 1)),
                       .names = "{fn}_{col}" ))
```

Note sure if any of these answers you question?

Comment: I am not looking for a distance from column max to every `Sepal.Length` value. The "max" I mentioned in my example had only the purpose of calculating a relative deviation between two observations. So my "max" changes with every pair of values compared.

Comment: then I have to tell you, that you are underestimating the problem: Imagine a line with a point at 1, another at 2 and another at 3. If the allowed distance for building groups is max 1, then point 1 is in a group with point 2 BUT 2 would also be in a group with point 3, which itself is 2 points away from 1 so what do you do? (The solution for this type of problem is some type of clustering and there are many types depending on what you are exactly trying to solve).